# What causes chrome to render body background for a while? How to prevent it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On Google Chrome, scrolling up and down at https://wolt.com/en/discovery temporarily shows the gray body background for some fraction of a second before showing the actual page content. This doesn't happen on Safari or Firefox.

In devtools, the "paint flashing" tool shows nothing happening in those areas. "Layer borders" flashes like crazy in those same areas.

I have two main questions, linked to each other:

- what causes this flashing behavior?
- how to modify the page so it doesn't happen?

Comment: Can't see what you mean. Is it the scroll-feedback-thing you are talking about? If so, you should have the same on Safari. So I guess it's not.

Comment: At least on several machines we've tested on, instead of the page just scrolling up and down, the part of the page coming into view is empty for some milliseconds and we see the light grey body background, then the elements and white background of the wrapper div appear.

Comment: Actually as I retest to make sure, the same thing happens in desktop safari but not as clearly (the delay seems shorter), on ios safari I can't replicate.

Comment: Commenting on my own question: the behavior was caused by too many layers - some bug fixes / hack done on the page promoted too many elements to their own layers. Removing those causes the page to be faster.